# Convex Manifold with constant mean curvature is hypersphere

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I wish to understand the proof the following theorem:

**Assume $M$ is an unbounded, compact, connected, strictly convex $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ hypersurface.
If the mean curvature of $M$ is constant, $M$ is a hypersphere.**

The proof starts like this:

With regard to $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ hypersurfaces, the equations become
\begin{align*}
R_{ijkl} &=h_{ik}h_{jl}-h_{il}h_{jk}\quad\quad &&(5.2.40)\\
h_{ijk}-h_{ikj}&=0\quad\quad&&(5.2.41)
\end{align*}
Using the $\Delta$ expression for the Laplacian $\Delta = \left ( \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} , \dots , \frac{\partial}{\partial x_n} \right )$ on $M$, then
$$\frac{1}{2} \Delta \big(\|{B}\|^2\big)= \frac{1}{2} \Delta\Big( \sum_{i,j} h_{ij}^2 \Big) = \sum_{i,j,k} h_{ijk}^2+\sum_{i,j}h_{ij}\Delta h_{ij}\quad (5.2.42)$$
with
\begin{align*}
\Delta h_{ij} &=\sum_{k}h_{ijkk},\\
\sum_l h_{ijkl}\omega^l &= dh_{ijk} - \sum_l h_{ljk}\omega^l_i - \sum_l h_{ilk}\omega^l_j -\sum_{l}h_{ijl}\omega_k^l.
\end{align*}

This is, where my first questions come up. I don't understand the usage of the second fundamental form here.

**How does its indexes work?**

**And where does the second equality in (5.2.42) come from?**

**Do I already know at this point that $\|B\|^2$ is a harmonic function?**

and continues with more facts about $h_{ijkk}$:
Using (5.2.41) as well as the Ricci equation, we have
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k}h_{ijkk}  &=\sum_{k}h_{kijk}\\
      &= \sum_{k}h_{kikj}+\sum_{k,l}h_{li}R_{lkjk}+\sum_{k,l}h_{kl}R_{lijk}\\
      &=\sum_{k}h_{kkij}+\sum_{k,l}\Big(h_{li}R_{lkjk}+h_{kl}R_{lijk}\Big)\\
      &=\sum_{k,l}\Big(h_{li}R_{lkjk}+h_{kl}R_{lijk}\Big)
\end{align*}
The last equality is due to $M$s mean curvature being constant.

**HERE I don't understand the second and the last equality.**

Thanks for your help!

Comment: unbounded and compact don't go well together.

Comment: Closed hypersurfaces are like that.

Comment: Compact implies bounded. A closed hypersurface which is unbounded is not compact.

Comment: Is that wrong? : A closed manifold is a type of topological space, namely a compact manifold without boundary.

Comment: @XiTong: The property you mention is usually called being "boundaryless". :) Being "unbounded" usually means "not contained in a ball". (Separately, a compact, boundaryless manifold is sometimes said to be "closed" or "a closed manifold", which can cause additional confusion, since for many people, "closed" means "a topologically closed set", i.e., a set whose complement is open.)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwuang Could you explain again what the difference between "boundaryless" and "unbounded" is? Does undbounded imply boundaryless but not the other way around?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to most my question.
In fact, my whole problem was the notation and the follow-up misunderstanding of $h_{ijkl}$
Here is the solution with the following notation $h_{ijkk}=h_{ij,kk}$ and 
$$\Delta h_{ij} \overset{(1)}{=}\sum_{k}h_{ijkk}$$

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2} \Delta \big(\|{B}\|^2\big) = &\frac{1}{2} \Delta\Big( \sum_{i,j} h_{ij}^2 \Big) \\
       = &\frac{1}{2} \sum_k \Big( \sum_{i,j} h_{ij}^2 \Big) _{,kk}\\
       = &\frac{1}{2} \sum_k \Big( 2\sum_{i,j} h_{ij}h_{ij,k} \Big) _{,k}\\
       = & \sum_k \Big( \sum_{i,j} h_{ij,k}^2+h_{ij}h_{ij,kk} \Big) \\
       \overset{using (1)}{=} &\sum_{i,j,k} h_{ijk}^2+\sum_{i,j}h_{ij}\Delta h_{ij}\quad (5.2.42)
\end{align*}

The answer to the second question lies in the Ricci equation being:
$$h_{ki,jk}-h_{ki,kj}=h_{li}R_{lkjk}+h_{kl}R_{lijk}.$$
Inserting it in $h_{ij,kk}$ which is equal to $h_{ki,jk}$ due to symmetry, solves the problem.

If the mean curvature is constant, $\frac{1}{n}\sum_k h_{kk}$ is constant, moreover $\sum_k h_{kk}$ is constant. Thus $\sum_k h_{kk,ij}=0.$

Still unanswered stays:

**Do I already know at this point that $∥B∥^2$ is a harmonic function?**